# Article spinner with 2 tiers

Tags: regex

I made an article spinner that used regex to find words in this syntax:

```
{word1|word2}
```

And then split them up at the "|", but I need a way to make it support tier 2 brackets, such as:

```
{{word1|word2}|{word3|word4}}
```

What my code does when presented with such a line, is take "{{word1|word2}" and "{word3|word4}", and this is not as intended.

What I want is when presented with such a line, my code breaks it up as "{word1|word2}|{word3|word4}", so that I can use this with the original function and break it into the actual words.

I am using c#.

Here is the pseudo code of how it might look like:

```
Check string for regex match to "{{word1|word2}|{word3|word4}}" pattern
If found, store each one as "{word1|word2}|{word3|word4}" in MatchCollection (mc1)
Split the word at the "|" but not the one inside the brackets, and select a random one (aka, "{word1|word2}" or "{word3|word4}")
Store the new results aka "{word1|word2}" and "{word3|word4}" in a new MatchCollection (mc2)
Now search the string again, this time looking for "{word1|word2}" only and ignore the double "{{" "}}"
Store these in mc2.
I can not split these up normally
```

Here is the regex I use to search for "{word1|word2}":

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\{.*?\}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection m = regexObj.Matches(originalText); //How I store them
```

Hopefully someone can help, thanks!

Edit: I solved this using a recursive method. I was building an article spinner btw.

Comment: Really quite a confusing question (?) -- it might help us help you to find a solution if we could know what you were doing with the `word1` and `word2` data - perhaps with a solution that does not involve regex (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not parsable using a regular expression, instead you have to use a recursive descent parser. Map it to JSON by replacing:

1. `{` with `[`
2. `|` with `,`
3. `wordX` with `"wordX"` (regex \w+)

Then your input

```
{{word1|word2}|{word3|word4}}
```

becomes valid JSON

```
[["word1","word2"],["word3","word4"]]
```

and will map directly to PHP arrays when you call `json_decode`.

In C#, the same should be possible with `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: the `Regex(@"...` makes me think the question is missing a C# tag... but I could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not completely sure WHAT you're asking for, but I'll give it a go:

If you want to get `{word1|word2}|{word3|word4}` out of any occurrence of `{{word1|word2}|{word3|word4}}` but not `{word1|word2}` or `{word3|word4}`, then use this:

```
@"\{(\{[^}]*\}\|\{[^}]*\})\}"
```

...which will *match* `{{word1|word2}|{word3|word4}}`, but with `{word1|word2}|{word3|word4}` in the first matching group.

I'm not sure if this will be helpful or even if it's along the right track, but I'll try to check back every once in a while for more questions or clarifications.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I scrapped the regex. I used a recursive method to do it.

Answer (score -1):

s = "{Spinning|Re-writing|Rotating|Content spinning|Rewriting|SEO Content Machine} is {fun|enjoyable|entertaining|exciting|enjoyment}! try it {for yourself|on your own|yourself|by yourself|for you} and {see how|observe how|observe} it {works|functions|operates|performs|is effective}."
print spin(s)

If you want to use the [square|brackets|syntax] use this line in the process function:

'/[(((?>[^[]]+)|(?R))*)]/x',